# Criar um ficheiro em Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Quero construir uma função em Python 3, que recebe como parametro um nome de um ficheiro texto e cria um novo ficheiro .txt, com o nome de double.txt, que é a copia do primeiro. Como é que faço isto?

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil

shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

`src` e `dst` são caminhos, onde `src` é o ficheiro atual e `dst` é o caminho da cópia do ficheiro

Doc: [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#module-shutil)

Resposta relacionada: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123238/3846065)